# How to be int array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, integer

```
import array as arr
a = arr.array('i', [22, 44, 66, 88])
result = []
for i in range(0, len(a)):
     result = (a[i]**2)/10
     print (result)
```

The output is 48.4 193.6 435.6 and 774.4
How to be output is 48 193 435 and 774 ?
Sorry for my english

Comment: ```(a[i]**2)//10```

Comment: thank you sir for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to precede `int()` to your variable result, if you want the variable to be saved as a float, but printed as an `int`:

```
import array as arr
a = arr.array('i', [22, 44, 66, 88])
result = []
for i in range(0, len(a)):
     result = (a[i]**2)/10
     print(int(result))
```

Otherwise, if you wish to save the variable as an integer:

```
import array as arr
a = arr.array('i', [22, 44, 66, 88])
result = []
for i in range(0, len(a)):
     result = int((a[i]**2)/10)
     print(result)
```

Finally, if you wish to add each integer to your list `result`:

```
import array as arr
a = arr.array('i', [22, 44, 66, 88])
result = []
for i in range(0, len(a)):
     result.append(int((a[i]**2)/10))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[48, 193, 435, 774]
```